# Error in WP_update_post

Tags: php, array, wp-update-post

i make php file outside from wordpress folder to edit wordpress post and i get error when i use this code.

wp_update_post

```
<?php include '/go1/wp-includes/post.php';?>

<?php
// Update post 1 hello word
  $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => 1,
      'post_title'   => 'This is the updated post title.',
      'post_content' => 'This is the updated content.',
  );

// Update the post into the database
  wp_update_post( $my_post );
?>
```

my error is:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant ARRAY_A - assumed 'ARRAY_A' in
>   D:\AAApc\training\XAMPP\htdocs\go1\wp-includes\post.php on line 3628
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in
>   D:\AAApc\training\XAMPP\htdocs\go1\wp-includes\post.php on line 664

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to using WordPress outside of WordPress is include the *wp-load.php* file:

So your code will like:

```
<?php 

// Include the wp-load'
include('YOUR_WP_PATH/wp-load.php');

// Update post 1 hello word
$my_post = array(
  'ID'           => 1,
  'post_title'   => 'This is the updated post title.',
  'post_content' => 'This is the updated content.',
);

// Update the post into the database
wp_update_post( $my_post );

?>
```

It's should work...

Once the *wp-load.php* file is included, the entire wealth of WordPress functions is provided to you. While the sample code above gets recent posts, you can do your own custom queries with [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) or [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts).

Comment: I'm glad you got this solved. Happy to help!