# How can I use wordpress functionality outside of WP framework

Tags: errors, get-posts

I require to retrieve a list of the recently created blog posts or any Query-based usage of WP posts inside my PHP website and not within WP framework.

I am new to Wordpress and stucked here. I already tried with include `wp-includes/post.php` file but i guess its still not working. Facing error regarding `undefined constant` and `function`. I don't know whether I am correct or not here. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: _"This is really urgent for me to accomplish."_ is not really a matter here. For more info see [ask]. Also, please use the search, the question has been answered several times already. If you find something, then please cast a close vote on your question to close it as duplicate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just simple, same reply from  Error in [WP_update_post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209919/error-in-wp-update-post/209921#209921) but in your case there is small change.

Just use `wp-load.php` as include. No need to include `post.php`. Once the `wp-load.php` file is included, the entire wealth of WordPress functions is provided to you.

For pull the recent post, you need to use `wp_get_recent_posts()` wordpress function which is from WP framework.

So your PHP code will like:

```
<?php 

// Include the wp-load'
include('YOUR_WP_PATH/wp-load.php');

// For example get the last 10 posts

// Returns posts as arrays instead of get_posts' objects
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 10
));

?>
```

Let me know if there is any doubt/query from this.

Answer (score 0):

> I require to retrieve a list of the recently created blog posts

1. Connect to WP database (name/user/pass can be fount in wp-config.php) and
2. execute SQL query same as with any other DB

This link will help you to find your way around easier.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description

That of course presuming you know php, not just what few WP functions does...

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I really appreciate this, but i don't think this resolves my purpose.  I require solution in context with error I am facing.

Comment: You probably getting error due usage of functions that are not defined. But I'm guessing. Can you provide code sample?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [BozidarS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/209941/45169)'s and [AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/209943/45169)'s solutions which are both good, if you want to access your WP from another domain you will probabbly want to use one of the WordPress API's. There are two good plugins that provide JSON REST API's:

- [WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/)
- [JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)

I personally prefer the latter, as WP-REST-API currently has a bug with the `post__in` filter (if you only want a specific list of ids you only have two options: get them one by one (multiple api calls) or get all unpaginated posts and filter out the results; another workaround for this bug is to create categories based on your REST needs and request posts by category).

However, word is out that WP-REST-API might become the "official" REST api for WordPress, but I don't have a reliable source to backup this statement. It's just hearsay.